# How can I instruct a JAXB Marshaller to scrub base64Binary data only for auditing?

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, jersey, marshalling

I am working in a JAXWS/JAXB web service environment.  JAXWS out of the box uses uses the JAXB to marshal/unmarshaler the web service payloads.

I also have a requirement to audit all request and response payloads.

I want a compact and concise marshaled representation of the payload for the audit (as a irrelevant side note - I am auditing using a java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue and some consumer threads to put batches of audit data in the audit datasource).

I have binary content(mtom) included on some web service response payloads but I DO NOT want to marshal audit these because the serialized base64 would be too large.

So my need is to create a marshaller (exclusively for auditng) that in all cases will scrub binary content but then NOT scrub for the prime purpose of marshalling web service response payloads.  I do XSD to Java xjc.  I need to use the same XSD/JAXB namespace for both contexts/marshallers.

Java type converter:

```
<jxb:javaType name=""
        parseMethod="com.xxx.xxx.ws.converter.XXXLongConverter.parseXXXLong" 
            printMethod="com.xxx.xxx.ws.converter.XXXLongConverter.printXXXLong" />
```

is will not work because 1. I would need to unregister the adapter [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#setAdapter%28java.lang.Class,%20A%29](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#setAdapter%28java.lang.Class,%20A%29%5d)
for the marshaller and I don't THINK I have a hook into that for JAXWS.  2.  I can't be guaranteed the class name that JAXB will decide to create in order to unregister it.

I created my own XMLAdapter and used the annox jaxb plugin
but that didn't really work for the same reasons the above didn't work.

Update: I now tried manually and reflectively walking through payload(to be audited) prior to marshalling to scrub the binary data but that got to be too much pain for what it was worth.

I should also mention that for brevity of the audit I am using jersey [JSON serialization supporting JAXB](http://jersey.java.net)
but I don't think that takes away or adds to my base problem:

How can I scrub data in one marshaller/unmarshaller but not another but both whose origin is the same JAXB context?

UPDATE:  <strike>Never figured out an elegate way to do this.  Not really possible at this point with the frameworks as they are.</strike>  UPDATE: Not true. Extending AttachmentMarshaller (I like this a lot and will use it) or creating a "need-aware" XmlAdapter would work for the audit specific marshaller as @Blaise answers below.

UPDATE:  If I may take this a step further to round out my use case...I mentioned above that for brevity of the audit I'd like to do Json Serialization of the [JSONJAXBContext](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/json/JSONJAXBContext.html) using jersey apis, specifically using the JSONMarshaller but the interface does not define setAdapter and setAttachmentMarshaller.  Coming out of [JSONJAXBContext.createJSONMarshaller()](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/json/JSONJAXBContext.html#createJSONMarshaller%28%29) is a [JSONMarshallerImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.14/com/sun/jersey/json/impl/JSONMarshallerImpl.java/) implementation which do define these this methods.  I will grudgingly cast to impl so I can set my custom attachment marshaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I scrub data in one marshaller/unmarshaller but not another
>   but both whose origin is the same JAXB context?

---

You could set your own implementation of `AttachemntMarshaller` and set it on the `Marshaller` that you are using for auditing.

**Root**

Below is a sample domain object with a `byte[]` property that by default will be represented as an element of type `base64Binary`.

```java
package forum8914008;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    byte[] bytes;

}
```

**Demo**

The demo code below first marshals the object to XML, and then marshals it a second time with a custom impplementation of `AttachmentMarshaller` set.

```java
package forum8914008;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.attachment.AttachmentMarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.bytes = "Hello World".getBytes();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);

        marshaller.setAttachmentMarshaller(new AttachmentMarshaller() {

            @Override
            public boolean isXOPPackage() {
               return true;
            }

            @Override
            public String addMtomAttachment(DataHandler arg0, String arg1,
                    String arg2) {
                return "fake";
            }

            @Override
            public String addMtomAttachment(byte[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    String arg3, String arg4, String arg5) {
                return "fake";
            }

            @Override
            public String addSwaRefAttachment(DataHandler arg0) {
                return "fake";
            }

        });
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  The first XML document could grow to be quite large if the byte[] was big.  The second XML document would stay the same size.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <bytes>SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=</bytes>
</root>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <bytes>
        <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="fake"/>
    </bytes>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I scrub data in one marshaller/unmarshaller but not another
>   but both whose origin is the same JAXB context?

---

You could support this use case with an `XmlAdapter`.

**XmlAdapter (ByteArrayAdapter)**

The following `XmlAdapter` is used to convert a `byte[]` to a `byte[]`.  In its default state it will return the original `byte[]`, it also has a audit state where it will return an empty byte[].

```java
package forum8914008;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ByteArrayAdapter extends XmlAdapter<byte[], byte[]> {

    private boolean audit;

    public ByteArrayAdapter() {
        this(false);
    }

    public ByteArrayAdapter(boolean audit) {
        this.audit = audit;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] marshal(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        if(audit) {
            return new byte[0];
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] unmarshal(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

**package-info**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used tp register the `XmlAdapter`.  When used at the package level it will apply to all properties of the specified type in that package (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html).

```java
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=ByteArrayAdapter.class, type=byte[].class)
package forum8914008;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
```

**Root**

Below is a sample domain object with a byte[] property that by default will be represented as an element of type base64Binary.

```java
package forum8914008;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    byte[] bytes;

}
```

**Demo**

The demo code below first marshals the object with the default state of the `ByteArrayAdapter` which will return the real `byte[]` and the marshals the object a second time with a stateful `ByteArrayAdapter` set which will convert all `byte[]` values to an empty `byte[]`.

```java
package forum8914008;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.bytes = "Hello World".getBytes();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);

        marshaller.setAdapter(new ByteArrayAdapter(true));
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code. The `XmlAdapter` would apply to all mapped fields/properties of type `byte[]`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <bytes>SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=</bytes>
</root>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <bytes></bytes>
</root>
```